# How do I configure my KDevelop installation to support KDE projects?

Tags: kde-plasma, kdevelop, kdevelop4

I am running Kubuntu 15.10 with KDevelop 4.7.1. I wish to create KDE specific applications such as Plasmoids for Plasma5 desktops. However, there is no option for developing KDE projects in the new projects menu. How do I configure KDevelop for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KDevelop depends on the `kapptemplate` package for KDE project templates.

Hence, install the `kapptemplate` package with:

`sudo apt-get install kapptemplate`

Unfortunately, while the `kapptemplate` package supports KF5, KDevelop doesn't. Therefore, the `kapptemplate` package must be copied to the KF4 templates directory using:

`sudo cp -Rv /usr/share/kdevappwizard/* /usr/share/kde4/apps/kdevappwizard/`

After restarting KDevelop and creating a new project, you should see the option for developing KDE projects.

Comment: Please, mark your post as answer. It is perfectly fine to answer your own posts. By the way, KDevelop 5 is KF-based, so it should support KF-style project templates.